# Elemet Display Below to Each other dint work in Block Element

Tags: html, css

Good day guys, anyone knows how to put the Web Development below of the fontawesome icon i tried display: block; but it don't work also i tried to put another  element also it don't work i tried to add also a 
 element nothing work as well heres the code, also new begginer here

```css
.section-service {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px,1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(20rem, auto);;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.section-service .color-service {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: crimson;
}
.section-service p {
    display: block;
}
.section-service i {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <section class="service section">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="section-title">Service</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="section-service">
                    <div class="web-dev color-service"><div><i class="fa fa-code"></i></div><p>Web Development</p></div>
                    <div class="web-design color-service"><p>Web Design</p></div>
                    <div class="wordpress color-service"><p>WordPress</p></div>
                    <div class="seo color-service"><p>SEO</p></div>
                    <div class="responsive color-service">Responsive Design</div>
                    <div class="learn color-service">Learn More</div>
                </div>
           </section>
```

Comment: You want to center horizontally and vertically the fontawesome icon and the p tag. in their container

Answer (score 1):

The container (`.color-service`) of them are `flex`. You need to set the `flex-direction` of the `.color-service` to `column`.

```
.section-service .color-service {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: crimson;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-direction:column; property in .color-service

[Please have a look attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXXon.png)